# Searching data from pagination second page error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to use CodeIgniter pagination and using the search option also.
when I search the content from the first page it was worked fine, but from the second place, it doesn't return any data.

```
$this -> load -> library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = site_url("admin/pcustomer/cprofile");
    $config['total_rows'] = $data['counts'];
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['display_pages'] = TRUE;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = "</ul>";
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['first_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['last_tag_open'] = "<li>";
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = "</li>";
    $config['suffix'] = '?' . http_build_query($_GET, '', "&");//array_merge($_GET, $_POST));
    $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'] .$config['suffix'];
    $this -> pagination -> initialize($config);
    $data['pagination'] = $this -> pagination -> create_links();
```

and my search

```
function ajxSearchProfile(){
     //$_GET = array_merge($_POST, $_GET);
    $result = $this->model_profile->searchCustomerProfile($this->input->post('term'));
    echo json_encode($result);

}
```

and model search function

```
 function searchCustomerProfile($search = ''){
    $this->db->like('name',$search);
    $this->db->select('id,name');
    $last=2;
    $this->db->where('lastAttendance',$last);
    $query = $this->db->get('customer');
    return $query->result();
}
and my ajax for search content
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#customer').select2({
    placeholder : "Select customer",
    allowClear : true,
    minimumInputLength :2,
    ajax : {
            url : '<?php echo base_url('admin/pcustomer/ajxSearchProfile'); 
             ?>',
            dataType :'json',
            type :'post',
            quietMillis :50,
            data : function(params){
                return {
                    term :params.term
                };
            },
            processResults : function(data){
                return {
                    results : $.map(data,function(item){
                        return {
                            text :item.name,
                            id :item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
    });
 </script>
```

may be this question was already asked but i am beginner in code igniter so i cann't understand well from that

Comment: What does your console says?

Comment: it returns the searching data successfully. it doesn't return any searching result when I search from second to last page  @D.Dimitrov

Comment: Sorry, I really can't understand. First of all you've said "it doesn't return any data", now you say it returns successfully, but no searching result? In your browser console do you see correctly returned json data?

Comment: @D.DimitrovI have received successful json result when I was searched by field name(like id,customer_name ) . it was not matter.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov Main Error is i cannot search any data from pagination other page except first page. because my baseurl was changed like "localhost/ci/cprofile/50?name="ram".

Comment: @D.Dimitrov i found main problem that is the limit value of page is append to my baseurl like 50 as apove so ajax search nothing but i cann't know how to solve that

Comment: in my second page on pagination url look like when i was search   "http://localhost/CI/admin/pcustomer/cprofile/100?customer=21198&mobile=&nearby="

Comment: from my first page when i make search my url look a like http://localhost/CI/admin/pcustomer/cprofile?customer=21075&mobile=&nearby=                         it was return json successfully

Comment: Could you post here your $config['base_url'], please? Also searchCustomerProfile

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CI/';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180057/discussion-between-d-dimitrov-and-ram).

Comment: function searchCustomerProfile($search = ''){
        $this->db->like('name',$search);
        $this->db->select('id,name');
        $last=2;
        $this->db->where('lastAttendance',$last);
        $query = $this->db->get('customer');
        return $query->result();
    }

Answer (score 0):

First,as per your url which is

```
localhost/ci/cprofile/50?name="ram"
```

then you are accepting the value in post request in your ajxSearchProfile function which is wrong. The correct syntax should be

```
function ajxSearchProfile(){    
     //$_GET = array_merge($_POST, $_GET);    
    $result = $this->model_profile->searchCustomerProfile($this->input->get('term'));    
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Now the solution to your problem is if you are searching via get method then you need to add these lines:-

```
$config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;  
$config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;  
$config['enable_query_string'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: search correctly but doesn't move any page.it show same content in all page @Varun Kumar

Comment: Kumar if i click 12th page it show same first page content

Comment: @Ram I think that what you say is happening because you are building data via ajax but you are not building your pagination again as per your search result